# how to position a list marker to the top instead of baseline?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an LI that contains only an image, set to around 100px tall. I have alphabetic markers on this list, but they are positioned at the base of the image, near the bottom left corner; can I position them straight above that, near the top left corner, instead?

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post to include HTML in a demo snippet.

Comment: Rather than moving the list marker, I'd just put in a custom pseudo-element and position it absolutely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `vertical-align: top;` on the image.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: lower-latin;
}
img {
  width: 200px;
}

ol.fixed img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>this list demonstrates the problem</li>
<li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRaJjp-zIlciVdoOvjvkxWU9O3TEkEU-ZcSzllCdKxR1qLtYVTiI2PJnYLkN1gZM4lW7V0&usqp=CAU"></li>
<li>by default, the marker is aligned with the bottom of the image</li>
</ol>

<ol class="fixed">
<li>this list demonstrates the solution</li>
<li><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRaJjp-zIlciVdoOvjvkxWU9O3TEkEU-ZcSzllCdKxR1qLtYVTiI2PJnYLkN1gZM4lW7V0&usqp=CAU"></li>
<li>the marker is now aligned with the top of the image, not by changing the marker alignment, but by changing the image alignment.</li>
</ol>
```